# Program used to run, now giving ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception?

Tags: java, buffer, image, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to run a code that my teacher posted online. It takes as input an image `(BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(args[0]));`

The first time I ran it it worked fine, now it's giving me `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` Exception at the line above.

Comment: Did you pass in an argument the 2nd time you ran it?

Comment: Seems like you are not passing the argument when you start the program from command line.

Comment: I am having the same problem using JDK 6.  All other programs can open the file correctly.

`Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096
 at com.sun.imageio.plugins.gif.GIFImageReader.read(GIFImageReader.java:960) ~[?:1.6.0_27]
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1438) ~[?:1.6.0_27]
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1298) ~[?:1.6.0_27]`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you didn't pass it any command line arguments? Then args would have a length of 0 and [0] would cause an array index out of bounds exception.